# Rigid body and angular motion

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

I am studying rigid body motion in Engineering Mechanics Dynamics by J.L. Meriam, 8th Edition. After he explains about rigid body motion in page 316 at the top of that page the following paragraph:

> "Note that the angular motion of a line depends only on its angular position with respect to any arbitrary fixed reference and on the time derivatives of the displacement. *Angular motion does not require the
> presence of a fixed axis, normal to the plane of motion, about which the line and the body rotate*."

I do not understand the italic section. Any rigid body needs a fixed axis for rotation. Why Meriam say it does not need that axis? I have searched extensively Google's sites and was not able to get a decent explanation for this issue. Please explain  with some example if Meriam's statement in italic is true.

Comment: Exactly what the authors mean I'm not sure, but I would guess they mean there is no unique axis about which the angular momentum is conserved. You can choose any point in the plane as an axis and you will find angular momentum is still conserved.

Comment: I don't think that the statement is clear or strict for a student textbook. Probably it tries to mean that any rotational motion can be decomposed into different frame systems depending on the basis of axes.

Comment: When you throw your phone in the air and it spins, does it spin about a fixed axis?

Comment: I looked at the pdf book . the Author write the equation $~\omega=\frac{d\theta}{dt}~$ this is only valid for 2D case. for 2D case is  "Note that the angular motion...." correct but not in general

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for a rotating body to have no fixed axis. Take a spinning top or a gyroscope, for example. The axis of rotation is not fixed. It precesses.

Answer (score 0):

If you have on object with some angular momentum the axis of rotation will only be stable if its rotating around one of its principle inertial axis and rotation would only remain stable after slight perturbation if its the principle axis with the highest moment of inertia. Consider [a T-handle in outer space rotating around an axis, that is not its principle axis with the highest moment of inertia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1n-HMSCDYtM). Even though angular momentum is conserved, as there are no forces acting on the T-handle floating in outer space, its rotational axis does change over time and therefore: "a fixed axis, normal to the plane of motion, about which the line and the body rotate"  does not exist.

Comment: "rotation would only remain stable after slight perturbation if its the principle axis with the highest moment of inertia". Shouldn't it be highest and lowest moment of inertia.  I thought instability only occurs at the intermediate moment of inertia.

Comment: @BobD My understanding is, that, if you would have an angular momentum, that is not pointing in the direction of the highest moment of inertia, the rotation axis will be oscillation around the axis of highest moment of inertia. I do not see, why a rotation around an axis close to the axis of lowest inertia would stabilize in a similar way, as one around an axis close to the axis of highest inertia would.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a video is worth a thousand words.
In this YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9wiRjUKctU), the general torque-free motion of a prolate axis-symmetric rigid body is visible. While the angular momentum is conserved, its dependence on a linear combination of three independent rotations around the body's principal axes results in a change of orientation of the instantaneous rotational axis.